# why the fd still available after shm_unlink()

Tags: linux, system-calls, shared-memory

I'm reading the source code in https://wayland-book.com/surfaces/shared-memory.html .

The author create a shared memory using shm_open(), and shm_unlink() it immediately, then ftruncate() the fd to a specific size, mmap() the fd and fill the region with pixels.
I'm so confused why the fd still available after shm_unlink().

according to the man page:

> The operation of shm_unlink() is analogous to unlink(2): it removes a shared memory object name, and, once all processes have unmapped the object, de-allocates and destroys the contents of the associated memory region. After a successful shm_unlink(), attempts to shm_open() an object with the same name will fail (unless O_CREAT was specified, in which case a new, distinct object is created).

so shm_unlink() will cause the memory destroyed because there is no process mmap
the region. But how fd still avaliable?

here is the code:

```
static int
create_shm_file(void)
{
    int retries = 100;
    do {
        char name[] = "/wl_shm-XXXXXX";
        randname(name + sizeof(name) - 7);
        --retries;
        int fd = shm_open(name, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR); 
        if (fd >= 0) {
            shm_unlink(name); // unlink immediately
            return fd;
        }
    } while (retries > 0 && errno == EEXIST);
    return -1;
}

static int
allocate_shm_file(size_t size)
{
    int fd = create_shm_file();
    if (fd < 0)
        return -1;
    int ret;
    do {
        ret = ftruncate(fd, size); //why the fd still available?
    } while (ret < 0 && errno == EINTR);
    if (ret < 0) {
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }
    return fd;
}
//after above, there was mmap
uint32_t *data = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

Comment: Because the `fd` was not closed. It's consistent with file operations. A file can be `open`ed and `unlink`ed immediately upon successful `open`.  The returned `fd` can be used to access the file's content until the `fd` is closed.

Comment: @NizamMohamed Thank you for your comment! I got it now, unlink doesn't mean to close the file, the file was still there.

Comment: Another advantage of this behavior : you create/open any file (a reference counter is set to 1), you unlink it, the file still exists in the file system as you didn't closed it (the reference counter is still 1), you can read/write into it. But as soon as your program exits, the reference counter drops to 0 and as it is marked "deleted", the file is automatically removed. Hence, when you want to make sure that files disappear as soon as your program terminates (normally or upon any error), it is a way to make it.